# Get info about document from iframe?

Tags: javascript

I notice some sites redirect the user when they are framed in an external domain.

How can I know when my site is loaded through an iframe?

And how can I know the domain of the site that is including it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ideal if you can get the iframe to tell you itself from a script inside the frame. For example it could call a parent function directly to tell it it's ready. Care is always required with cross-frame code execution as things can happen in an order you don't expect. Another alternative is to set ‘var isready= true;’ in its own scope, and have the parent script sniff for ‘contentWindow.isready’ (and add the onload handler if not).

If for some reason it's not practical to have the iframe document co-operate, you've got the traditional load-race problem, namely that even if the elements are right next to each other:

```
<img id="x" ... />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('x').onload= function() {
        ...
    };
</script>
```

there is no guarantee that the item won't already have loaded by the time the script executes.

The ways out of load-races are:

on IE, you can use the ‘readyState’ property to see if something's already loaded;
if having the item available only with JavaScript enabled is acceptable, you can create it dynamically, setting the ‘onload’ event function before setting source and appending to the page. In this case it cannot be loaded before the callback is set;
the old-school way of including it in the markup:

```
<img onload="callback(this)" ... />
```

Inline ‘onsomething’ handlers in HTML are almost always the wrong thing and to be avoided, but in this case sometimes it's the least bad option.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at framebreakers in javascript this is exactly what you are looking for.

here are some examples http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/framebreak.shtml

Answer (score 0):

not tested but should work:

```
if (self != top){
alert('FRAMED! URL = ' + top.location.href);
 top.location = self.location;
}
```